# android onDraw not drawing png

Tags: android

I have a class called Preview that is added as a child to one of my FrameLayouts. This is the Preview's onDraw method. fingerprint.png is in my drawable folder, and

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    System.out.println("on draw");

    Resources res = getResources();
    fingerprint = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.fingerprint);
    fingerprint.draw(canvas);
    //fingerprintScaled.draw(canvas);

}
```

"on draw" prints, but the fingerprint image is not rendered.

Comment: You might consider moving `getResources()` out to the constructor or somewhere so it will only get called once, no need to get a new reference everytime onDraw() is called. I don't think that is the root of your problem though. As a troubleshooting step perhaps try drawing something other than your drawable, (a shape or line or something primitive) to see if anything is drawing at all. That could tell you whether the issue is with your drawable or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is not drawing is because you are calling draw wrong.
in protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
do something like this (except dont decode stuff in onDraw)

```
Bitmap fingerprint = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.icon_resource);

canvas.drawBitmap (fingerPrint, aMatrix, paintToDraw);
```

this should draw your bitmap properly.